# How to make pagination?

Tags: vue.js, pagination, axios

How to make pagination. I tried many times already, but I can’t do it. I have to paginate without Laravel. The problem is that I can not make a cycle that will display the number of pages, each page should have 10 posts, and there are 98 posts in total. I made the property to be calculated, thanks to which you can find out how many pages there will be. I made a page switch that works. But for some reason, the cycle with which I will display the number of pages does not work for me, I cannot understand what the problem is?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hI0VF.jpg)

My Vue js:
    import axios from 'axios';

```
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {

    return{
      counter: 1,
      zero: 0,
      posts: [],
      createTitle: '',
      createBody: '',
      visiblePostID: '',

    }
  },

  watch: {
      counter: function(newValue, oldValue) {
          this.getData()
      }
  },
  created(){
      this.getData()
   },

   computed: {
     evenPosts: function(posts){
       return Math.ceil(this.posts.length/10);

       }
     },

   methods: {
      getData() {
          axios.get(`http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_start=${this.counter}+${this.zero}&_limit=10`).then(response => {
              this.posts = response.data
          })
      },
      // even: function(posts) {
      //   return Math.ceil(this.posts.length/10)
      // },

        deleteData(index, id) {
          axios.delete('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' + id)
                    .then(response => {
                      console.log('delete')
                        this.posts.splice(index, 1);
                      })
                    .catch(function(error) {
                        console.log(error)
                    })
                  },
        addPost() {
          axios.post('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/', {
            title: this.createTitle,
            body: this.createBody
            }).then((response) => {
              this.posts.unshift(response.data)
              })
            },
        changePost(id, title, body) {
          axios.put('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' + id, {
            title: title,
            body: body
          })
        },
      },
  }
```

My html:

```
<div id="app">
      <div class="smallfon">
        <div class="blocktwitter"><img src="src/assets/twitter.png"  class="twitter"/></div>
        <div class="addTextPost">Add a post</div>
        <input type="text" v-model="createTitle" class="created"/>
        <input type="text" v-model="createBody" class="created"/>
        <div><button  @click="addPost()" class="addPost">AddPost</button></div>
        <div class="post1">
          <div class="yourPosts">Your Posts</div>
          <ul>
            <li v-for="(post, index) of posts" class="post">
              <p><span class="boldText">Title:</span> {{ post.title }}</p>
              <p><span class="boldText">Content:</span> {{ post.body }}</p>
              <button  @click="deleteData(index, post.id)" class="buttonDelete">Delete</button>
              <button @click="visiblePostID = post.id" class="buttonChange">Change</button>
              <div v-if="visiblePostID === post.id" class="modalWindow">
              <div><input  v-model="post.title" class="changePost"><input  v-model="post.body" class="changePost"></div>
              <button type="button" @click="changePost(post.id, post.title, post.body)" class="apply">To apply</button>
            </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
              <button type="button" @click="counter -=1" class="prev">Предыдущая</button>
              <!-- <div class="counter">{{ counter }}</div> -->  <span v-for="n in evenPosts" :key="n.id">{{ n }} </span>
              <button type="button" @click="counter +=1" class="next">Следущая</button>

              <!-- <span v-for="n in evenPosts" :key="n.id">{{ n }} </span> -->

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You can't return pagination count if you fetch 10 items by request ( *`axios.get(...&_limit=10)`*). The computed `evenPosts` will always returned 1 i.e. `Math.ceil(10/10) == 1`

Comment: Please tell me how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you bind a limit to your fetching request (*`axios.get(...&_limit=10)`*), you can't return a paginate count because your computed `evenPost` property will always return 1 i.e `Math.ceil(10/10) == 1`

To fix your pagination, remove the parameters query to get the data:

```js
getData() {
  axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then(response => {
    this.posts = response.data
  })
}
```

Then change the default `counter` page to `0` and add a computed property to return 10 posts based on it:

```js
data () {
  return {
    counter: 0,
    //...
  }
},
computed: {
   paginatedPosts() {
    const start = this.counter * 10;
    const end = start + 10;
    return this.posts.slice(start, end);
  }
}
```

Now you can iterate on this property:

```html
<ul>
  <li v-for="(post, index) of paginatedPosts" class="post">
    ...
  </li>
</ul>
```

*[Basic live example](https://jsfiddle.net/StpFlp_DDK/ybz8xpqf/)*